# Right way to avoid two equals for loops in AutoMapper

Tags: c#, mapping, automapper

I'm using `.AfterMap(source,destination)` to do some stuff. I have 2 for loops that are the same but with different lists. Is it any way with AutoMapper to avoid having the 2 loops?

```
.AfterMap((source, destination) => {
   var destinationItems1 = destination.List1.ToList();
   for(i = 0; source.List1.count; i++){ 
       //CODE 
   }

   var destinationItems2 = destination.List2.ToList();
   for(i = 0; source.List2.count; i++){ 
      //SAME_CODE_THAN_ABOVE_BUT_DIFFERENT_LIST 
   }
}
```

Actually it is not same code. First loop I check if object source attribute is equal to destination..
And same for second loop, but for its attribute.

Comment: Separate same code in another method and pass your list as parameter?

Comment: Are the types of the list same?

Comment: They're different type

Comment: Please add full code, with the inner parts of loops. If you think that code for your models can help, add it as well.